# Javascript array.push() do not add but replace it

Tags: javascript, arrays, bootstrap-switch

I have some checkboxes styled with `bootstrapSwitch`.
I wrote a script that have to add value of checkbox to an array when bootstrapSwitch `state` is true.

This is my code :

```
$('input[name^=skill]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

    //alert(state);
    //var s = [];

    var s = new Array();

    if( state === true )
    {
        //var value = $(this).val();
        s.push( $(this).val() );

        console.log(s);//(value)

    }

        console.log(s);//(value)
});
```

But surprisingly `push` method replace the value and my `s` array always have one index.

Would you please let me know why is that?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Define array out of the handler..Or it will be initialized to `[](empty-array)` every time handler is invoked...

Comment: That's because you're re-creating `s` upon each click. Try to move the declaration of `s` outside of the event callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var s = new Array();
```

Define this out of the handler function.

It's always 1 because you're recreating it everytime.

Comment: Shame on me... :-)... I'll accept your answer as soon as site let me to do that

Comment: It happen sometimes :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = new Array();// this line should be out side of function. so it will not be new object everytime
```

so try this

```
var s = new Array();// this line should be here. so it will not be new object everytime

$('input[name^=skill]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

    //alert(state);
    //var s = [];

    var s = new Array();

    if( state === true )
    {
        //var value = $(this).val();
        s.push( $(this).val() );

        console.log(s);//(value)

    }

        console.log(s);//(value)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = [];

$('input[name^=skill]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

        //alert(state);
        //var s = [];



        if( state === true )
        {
            //var value = $(this).val();
            s.push( $(this).val() );

            console.log(s);//(value)

        }

            console.log(s);//(value)
    });
```

Just declare the array outside. User [] instead on new Array() as it is faster.